# Happstack SSL error - wrong tag

Tags: haskell, ssl, certbot, happstack

I am trying to run happstack-tls server using certificate generated by certbot, however, when I run it I get `user error (error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag)` and program ends. I tried to use both pem and der versions of certificate, but without success.

Here is the code:

```
conf :: TLSConf
conf = nullTLSConf
  { tlsCert = "csr-certbot.der"
  , tlsKey = "key-certbot.pem"
  , tlsPort = 8000
  }

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Server running..."
  simpleHTTPS conf app
```

What may be wrong? Should I provide some more informations?